# Does anyone know why i got this exception using OCR Tesseract in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, tesseract

I'm trying to use Tesseract in C++ for a small personal project.
It's my first time using tesseract in C++ and I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to code.

I followed this tutorial to install Tesseract with VB :
https://www.technical-recipes.com/2021/getting-started-with-tesseract-optical-character-recognition-ocr-library-in-visual-studio/

But when i use the code to try if everything is working, my code raise an exception.

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaa9o.png)

The code is :

```
{
    char* outText;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI* api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
    if (api->Init("C:\\Users\\Kilian\\source\\repos\\LecteurHdv\\tessdata", "fra")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Open input image with leptonica library
    Pix* image = pixRead("C:\\Users\\Kilian\\Pictures\\TestOcr\\test.png");
    api->SetImage(image);
    // Get OCR result
    outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
    printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);

    // Destroy used object and release memory
    api->End();
    delete api;
    delete[] outText;
    pixDestroy(&image);

    return 0;
}
```

The only changes I made to the base code were changing the language to French and changing the image folder.

Does anyone have any idea why i got this exception ?
Sorry if a post already exist about that.

Thanks you all for your replies.

Comment: What line of code throws the exception?

Comment: Are you using the correct binaries for your compiler. Since this is msvc make sure you don't mix debug with release on top of selecting binaries compiled for Visual Studio 2015 to 2019.

Comment: ***Does anyone have any idea why i got this exception ?*** I think the debugger may tell you more than just the breakpoint. I believe you have some heap corruption but I am not sure.

Comment: Is `api->GetUTF8Text()` returning a non-null string?

Comment: The line of code throwing the exception is ``` delete api;``` @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @drescherjm I think you are right, when i click on continue after the exception. I got "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFFBDDCF259 (ntdll.dll) in LecteurHdv.exe: 0xC0000374: A memory segment has been damaged (parameters: 0x00007FFFBDE377F0)." 
About the compiler, it's my first time using VS so i don't anything about that, Do you have an exemple of what i should use or not use?

Comment: @jwezorek Yes it's not null, i got the text from the image i gave.

Comment: Comment out everything from `Pix* image = ...` up to and including the `printf`, and the deallocations of `image` and `outText`  and see if you still get an exception.

Comment: I tried and i still got the exception @jwezorek

Comment: Comment out `api->Init()` and `api->End()`.

Comment: do I let the rest comment out?

Comment: yes. I just want to verify that Init() is corrupting memory.

Comment: I still got the exception, to be sure i'm supposed to just have that part of the code `
#include <baseapi.h>
#include <allheaders.h>
int main()
{
    char* outText;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI* api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    delete api;
    return 0;
}`

Comment: Could be related to these issues: 
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/2151
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1670
bugs in tesseract per locale.

Comment: Thanks you i will try to understand all that

Comment: yeah i don't know ... it is either some bug in Tesseract or something is wrong with your Tesseract binaries, but in that case yopur program would typically fail to link.

Comment: Is there any way to get a usable tesseract ?  I'm trying to find answer to why the constructor corrupt my memories but for now I didn't find anything related

Comment: Maybe your input is the problem. Maybe you should ask this question at the github page.

Comment: thanks all for all your replies i will try to ask on the github page